# Given length of one side and its median and another median in a triangle. Find area of the triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Given the triangle $ABC$. If length of medians $AM=7.5$ and $BN=12$ and side $AC=6$, find the area of the triangle.

**NOTE**: Solution must not use any special formula or trigonometric functions.

My attempt : $NM$ is half of $AB$ in length, Triangles $ANO$ and $MOB$ have same amount of area.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleMedian.html

Comment: Could you share the work you've done in an attempt to answer the question?  What do you know about the medians of a triangle?  [Medians of a triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)).

Comment: @amWhy I have been searching for solution for too long and nearly no useful founds. I've added what I've found to the main post.

Comment: Have you sketched the triangle, labeling all the points? If you can upload it, that would be great, too.  But do not fret if you haven't the means to upload it as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AM$ and $BN$ meet at G(centroid).

Property of the centroid is that it divides a median in the ratio $2:1$.

Therefore $AG=5$ and $GB=4$.

Therefore $ABG$ is a $5,4,3$ i.e right-angled triangle whose area is $10$.

Therefore the total area is $60$

Comment: typo: $GN=4$ and $GB=8$. and also area becomes 36, not 60 and $ABG$'s area is 6 not 10. You were too much in hurry!

Comment: I don't think that.

Comment: What is the area of triangle ABC?

Comment: Sorry- my mistake. don't you mean $AGN$ is a right-angled triangle with sides 3 and 4 and 5 which is $\frac16$ of $ABC$ and equal 6?

Comment: No I am taking ABG is a right angle triangle in this case. Actually I always solve questions on my mobile so sometime some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the lengths to solve for the semiperimeter ( which is half the perimeter ). Then set up Heron's formula (which would be area is equal to the square root of semiperimeter  multiplied by semiperimeter  minus side a multiplied by semiperimenter minus side b multiplied by semiperimenter minus side c. Here are the formulas you need:

S(semiperimeter)= 1/2 (a+b+c)

A (area)=√S (S-a)(S-b)(S-c)

Comment: Could you mention how to find length of the other 2 sides ($AB$ and $CB$)?

Comment: Medians divide into 6 equal areas. After finding one of them you can multiply by 6 to get the entire area.

Comment: Hello princess. Actually in this case we don't have all 3 sides. In this case we have only one side and 2 medians. So please amend your answer.